# Pandas to_csv index=False not working when writing incremental chunks

Tags: python, pandas, csv, chunks

I'm writing a fixed-width file to CSV. Because the file is too large to read at once, I'm reading the file in chunks of 100000 and appending to CSV. This is working fine, however it's adding an index to the rows despite having set `index = False`.

How can I complete the CSV file without index?

```
infile = filename
outfile = outfilename
cols = [(0,10), (12,19), (22,29), (34,41), (44,52), (54,64), (72,80), (82,106), (116,144), (145,152), (161,169), (171,181)]

for chunk in pd.read_fwf(path, colspecs = col_spec, index=False, chunksize=100000):
chunk.to_csv(outfile,mode='a')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`to_csv` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) has a `header` parameter, indicating if to output the header. In this case, you probably do *not* want this for writes that are not the first write.

So, you could do something like this:

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_fwf(...)):
    first = i == 0
    chunk.to_csv(outfile, header=first, mode='a')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found the answer to my question hidden in the action of getting up, leaving work and going home. I should have put the index=False in chunk.to_csv(outfile, index=False, mode='a') rather than in read.fwf()...

Comment: @user3867061 why not add it as an answer then